# Why the two trs were parsed as just the same first tr by lxml?

Tags: python, html-parsing, lxml

I draw the simple structure for the `target_html`:

```
table--div--tr[id="tr1"]
     |--tr[id="tr2"]
     |--tr[id="tr3"]
     |--tr[id="tr4"]
```

To extract the first tr from target_html with lxml.

```
target_html="""
<table id="t1"> 
<div id="div1"> 
<tr id="tr1"> 
<td>11</td> 
<td>12</td> 
</tr> 
</div> 

<tr id="tr2">
<td>21</td> 
<td>22</td> 
</tr>

<tr id="tr3"> 
<td>31</td> 
<td>32</td> 
</tr> 

<tr id="tr4"> 
<td>41</td> 
<td>42</td> 
</tr> 
</table> """

doc=lxml.html.fromstring(target_html)
for item in doc.xpath('//tr[1]'):
    print(item.text_content())
```

Expexted result parsed by lxml:

```
11 
12
```

The real result parsed by lxml:

```
11 
12     

21 
22
```

Why two trs were parsed as `tr[1]`?

Comment: `//` does a wildcard for all occurrences of `tr[1]`.  Based on your example, `//div/tr[1]` will produce your expected result.

Comment: I believe it is because `//tr[1]` means "Anytime there are one or more tr's at the same level, pick the first one." `tr1` is underneath a div, so it isn't at the same level as the other three, so it is chosen. `tr2` is also chosen, as it is the first of three all at the same level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xpath `//tr[1]` means select any `tr` element that is the first child element (with that name) of its parent.

The following `tr` is selected because it's the first `tr` child of `div`:

```
<tr id="tr1"> 
<td>11</td> 
<td>12</td> 
</tr>
```

The following `tr` is selected because it's the first `tr` child of `table`:

```
<tr id="tr2">
<td>21</td> 
<td>22</td> 
</tr>
```

To grab the first occurrence, first wrap the xpath in parentheses...

```
doc.xpath('(//tr)[1]')
```